# how to call this by id instead of tagname?

Tags: javascript

How can I get this to work by assigning an id?

```
<p id="randtext">text 1</p>
<p id="randtext">text 2</p>
<p id="randtext">text 3</p>
```

I do not wish for it to randomize all text under `<p>`

Here is the code:

```
var current = 0,
    slides = document.getElementsById("randtext");

setInterval(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.opacity = 0;
  }
  current = (current != slides.length - 1) ? current + 1 : 0;
  slides[current].style.opacity = 1;
}, 9999);
```

Thanks

Comment: Use a common class instead of generating random ids (which is a massive anti-pattern)

Comment: can you show some examples?

Comment: Change `slides = document.getElementsById("randtext");` to `slides = document.querySelectorAll(".randtext");` and change `id="randtext"` to `class="randtext"`

Comment: Ids _must_ be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: not seem to work

Comment: Works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/6rhdts5n/. The only amendment was to hide all but the first element on page load. If you have a specific issue, please edit the question to show a complete example

Comment: oh yes, how can i ,make it slide instead of up down?

Comment: animating it is a separate question, really IMO. And you could do some research into it first, there are bound to be tutorials online, and existing code you can use.

Comment: I've edited the question to remove the `[jquery]` tag as the question does not contain any jQuery. If you feel like this edit was made in error to your question, let me know and I can roll the edit back.